# Is there a way to group hex colors using php

Tags: php, colors, hex, color-picker

Im using a PHP color extract class that i found in GitHub for a project that im working on.

Color Extractor Class

```
https://github.com/humanmade/Colors-Of-Image
```

Question i have is, is there a way to group colors to main colors.

Example: if you take red color above class will give

```
#ff0000 
#e50000 
#cc0000
```

so on depending on the image. What i want to do is make all these colors as red before i save to database.

Id there any formula to check a color range? I search for days but couldn't find any information. Appreciate your time.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you only want to save the red channel of an complete image, as an image, in your database?

Comment: @KIKO Software i want to generalize the colors. Like any red hex in to red and any orange hex in to orange.

Comment: You're talking like a human, not a programmer. Are you saying that if a pixel in an image as any red in it, you want to make that pixel full red `#FF0000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how many groups you would like to have BUT since three pairs are responsible for RED-GREEN-BLUE, you could divide the whole string (without hash) into pairs,  then calculate each pair into decimal with `hexdec` function and see if they are within a certain range of your choice.

i.e: if the hexdec result is way bigger than the sum of the second and third pair, you're most likely looking at some variant of red.

sample code:

```
$colors = [
    '#ff0000',
'#e50000',
'#cc0000',
];

foreach ($colors as $hex){
    list($redHex,$greenHex,$blueHex) = str_split(trim($hex,'#'),2);
    $redVal = hexdec($redHex);
    $greenVal = hexdec($greenHex);
    $blueVal = hexdec($blueHex);
    if($redVal > $greenVal+$blueVal){
        echo $hex.' is most likely red';
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems hexdec only allow RGB?

Comment: see my updated answer with sample code of what I meant